# Naming conventions for test cases in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I encountered the weirdest issue with Eclipse Kepler, Service Release 1. I set up a class to implement some test cases by extending `junit.framework.TestCase`, like so:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class PublicTests extends TestCase {

    @Override
    public void setUp(){
        ...
    }
```

Then I added some `public void` test case methods, all of the names of which started with the prefix `test`. For example, `testBasicAdd`. Then, I added another `public void` test case method, named `stressTestForAdd()`, and when I ran all the test cases, that particular one was not even recognized as a test case and therefore not run. I made sure that it was actually not recognized as a test case by deleting all other methods, thus creating an instance of `TestCase` with `stressTestForAdd` as its only test case, and when I re-ran the suite I received a neat `AssertionError` stating that I hadn't authored any test cases in my file. When I added the prefix `test` to my method, creating the unwieldy name `testStressTestForAdd`, the test case was recognized.

I haven't encountered the need to have the `test` prefix in a jUnit test case anywhere in the relevant literature, not even as a convention. Is this a bug of Eclipse, perhaps? Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: What version of JUnit are you using?

Comment: Did you forget the @Test annotation?

Comment: You don't extend `TestCase` in JUnit 4 and higher. Instead, you annotate your test methods with `@Test` and do a static import on the `Assert` class.

Comment: I'm using jUnit4. There are two ways I can do it; either extending `TestCase` or by statically importing `Assert`. In my case, only the first option is viable because of a server I'm using which kind of wants things to be that way. Also see the comment I made in cmd's comment below.

Comment: It really sounds like you're using JUnit 3.  Can you double-check your class path just to be sure?

Comment: Absolutely. Here's proof that I'm using jUnit4: http://imageshack.com/a/img28/9131/yzhz.png

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

In early versions of JUnit e.g. JUnit 3, methods are executed as tests as long as the method name begins with `test`

e.g.

```
 public void testGetName()
```

In JUnit 4, support for annotations was introduced, thus in JUnit 4, you may name your test method anything you desire as long as you annotate it with `@Test`

e.g.

```
@Test
public void getName()
```

Comment: Hmmm... This appears to not have worked in my case. I went ahead and created a test case called `beer()`, imported `org.junit.Test` and used the @Test annotation, and the test case was still not detected. I'm pretty sure at this point that it is not something Eclipse - related, since I have access to a server that executes jUnit test cases against a baseline code so long as you upload both, and the server itself could not detect the test case either.